# VS 2012 Start UI Windows from VSPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vspackage

i've started to work with the VS2012 extensibility possibilities. I did the first few Walkthroughs and now I'm trying get further on. What I'm trying is pretty easy I guess... I'm trying to build a simply vspackage which starts an UI window. Actually i do not find any howto or sample code.

Do you have some links with further information about doing something like that ?
Thanks for you help..

Iki

Answer (score 0):

You can find initial information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb165468.aspx).
Here is my code for menu item:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialization of the package; this method is called right after the package is sited, so this is the place
    /// where you can put all the initialization code that rely on services provided by VisualStudio.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine ("Entering Initialize() of: {0}", this);
        base.Initialize();

        // Add our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the .vsct file)
        OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
        if ( null != mcs )
        {
            // Create the command for the menu item.
            CommandID menuCommandID = new CommandID(GuidList.guidPackageProject, (int)PkgCmdIDList.Impl);
            OleMenuCommand menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID);
            mcs.AddCommand( menuItem );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is the callback used to execute a command when the a menu item is clicked.
    /// See the Initialize method to see how the menu item is associated to this function using
    /// the OleMenuCommandService service and the MenuCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyForm form = new MyForm();
        form.ShowDialog();   //  Here your form is opening
    }
```

Comment: my problem is to start something like WPF out of a VSPACKAGE

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for a solution to this recently as I also needed to start a WPF form from a VSPackage. I have got things working after a couple of hours searching various topics on this and some good ol' trial and error.

I had an existing WPF-Project in a separate solution, which had to be merged into a VSPackage. Here's the steps to get this working:

- Create a new Solution of Project type 'Visual Studio Package'
- Make sure you select the 'Tool Window' option in the VS Package
  Wizard (see the image below)

[image: VSPackageWizardToolWindowOption]

- Now that the Solution has been created, add the already existing
  WPF-Project to it (Right-Click 'Solution', *Add->Existing Project*) **NOTE:** It might be wise to copy the WPF-project to the Solution folder prior to adding it to the Solution.
- Make sure you create a reference to the WPF-Project from your
  VSPackage-Project and (if necessary) edit the namespaces of the WPF-Project to meet those of the VSPackage-Project, or the other way around.

Your Solution will now look something like this:

[image: VSPackageSolutionWithWPFProjectAdded]

Now, you need to edit **MyToolWindow.cs**:

```
// Original:    
base.Content = new MyControl();

// Change to:    
base.Content = new MainWindow();
```

Make the following changes to **VSPackage1Package.cs** (or whatever your *Package.cs file is called)

```
// Original
        private void ShowToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the instance number 0 of this tool window. This window is single instance so this instance
            // is actually the only one.
            // The last flag is set to true so that if the tool window does not exists it will be created.
            ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, true);
            if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.CanNotCreateWindow);
            }
            IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());
        }

// Change to:
        private void ShowToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the instance number 0 of this tool window. This window is single instance so this instance
            // is actually the only one.
            // The last flag is set to true so that if the tool window does not exists it will be created.
            //ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, true);
            //if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
            //{
            //    throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.CanNotCreateWindow);
            //}
            //IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
            //Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());
          MainWindow mainwin = new MainWindow();
            mainwin.Show();
        }
```

If you get no build errors, you should be fine.

To test if your WPF-form opens, Press 'Start' to run the VSPackage in a new 'Experimental' Visual Studio instance. If everything went OK, you will find and should be able to run your WPF-from from the *View->Other Windows* menu.

If you don't see your VSPackage listed in the menu, close your 'Experimental' Visual Studio instance. Then Clean en Build your Solution and press 'Start' again. It should show up now.